# Is the destroyed session value NULL and or empty value?

Tags: php, session-variables

A session variable has a value at the time of construction.

If the session variable was destroyed then the destroyed session contains NULL and or empty value?

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: @Md. Sahadat Hossain , Please see this [link](http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/)

Comment: are you trying to use session_destroy() or unset()? I cant answer without knowing details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is NULL. If you are coding something that holds session like a login system (from link provided) -and you want to log a user out - you want to unset the id and cookies as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. As the result, when I use `session_destroy()` for logout, in that link the `$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session` value changes as the `$_SESSION['login_user']=NULL` . Yes?

Comment: That should work, yes. Also, if you are storing cookies for the users and they log out you want to clear those as well. you can do that by: `setcookie("user", "", time() - 3600);` -pretty much setting the cookie to expire in the past.